# In an exact cover problem, what makes this choice of r nondeterministic?

Tags: algorithm

## Background:

The following is pseudocode from Donald Knuth's paper: [Dancing Links](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047.pdf)

```
If A is empty, the problem is solved; terminate successfully.
Otherwise choose a column, c (deterministically).
Choose a row, r, such that A[r, c] = 1 (nondeterministically).
Include r in the partial solution.
For each j such that A[r, j] = 1,
   delete column j from matrix A;
   for each i such that A[i, j] = 1,
       delete row i from matrix A.
Repeat this algorithm recursively on the reduced matrix A.
```

Knuth then writes:

> The nondeterministic choice of r means that the algorithm essentially
>   clones itself into independent subalgorithms; each subalgorithm
>   inherits the current matrix A, but reduces it with respect to a
>   different row r.

### My assumptions about (non)deterministic algorithms:

I *think* the choice of c is deterministic because the number of columns in the exact constraint matrix A is known in advance.

I *think* this choice of r is nondeterministic because the number of available rows is not known in advance.  The set of available rows depends on the solver's **current state**.   For example, for a particular state of the solver, the next row satisfying `A[r, c] = 1` may be nearby.  In another state, it may be much further away.

I came to the above assumptions by reading the [Wikipedia entry on nondeterministic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm), specifically:

> An algorithm that solves a problem in nondeterministic polynomial time
>   can run in polynomial time or exponential time depending on the
>   choices it makes during execution.

## Question

How does the algorithm's being nondeterministic make it "essentially clone itself"?  This seems more like a property of recursion than of deterministic algorithms.

Comment: I think that Wikipedia article is wrong; or at least, it defines the term "nondeterministic" in a very different way from how Knuth is using it. (They're related, but not in a way that you can easily puzzle out on your own if you're not familiar with how Knuth is using it.) Read this one instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine.

Comment: @ruakh, thank you for pointing me towards this definition.  I can see how the computation tree of a Nondeterministic Turing Machine as described on Wikipedia matches Knuth's word choice.  Every branch of the NTM's computation tree is one of Knuth's "clones".
(For future answer-seekers, see [resolution of multiple rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-deterministic_Turing_machine#Resolution_of_multiple_rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of c is deterministic because there are no wrong choices (but some rules for making that choice are better than others; see the discussion shortly after the pseudocode in Knuth's writeup). The algorithm makes one arbitrary choice and moves on. In recursive calls, the number of columns that remain in the matrix is not known in advance.

The choice of r is nondeterministic because the algorithm needs to try all possible choices to find all of the solutions. Knuth probably described it that way because (1) he's an old-school CS theorist, and that's how it would be described in automata/formal language theory (2) it highlights the fact that the nondeterministic branches have no dependency on one another and hence are amenable to parallelism.